# Calling queue variable processed outside of __init__ getting Empty values in python

Tags: python, multithreading, class, websocket, constructor

I have made a python script to receive live ticks and put it inside a queue for further processing but my problem is that as I have defined the `queue` variable in the class `__init__` method and putting the received ticks by calling another function inside the same `class` but when calling it from another function it gets the variable from `__init__` and not directly from other function where I `put` the values into the queue it is getting `queue.empty` error.
Edit: "If you have any suggestion to improve my question for a better understanding you are welcome."

My code:

`main.py`:

```
from stream import StreamingForexPrices as SF
from threading import Thread, Event
import time
from queue import Queue, Empty

def fetch_data(data_q):
    while True:
        time.sleep(10)
        # data_q.put("checking")
        data = data_q.get(False)
        print(data)

def start():
    events = Queue()

    fetch_thread = Thread(target=fetch_data, args=(events,))
    fetch_thread.daemon = True
    fetch_thread.start()

    prices = SF(events)
    wst = Thread(target=prices.conn)
    wst.daemon = True
    wst.start()
    while not prices.ws.sock.connected:
        time.sleep(1)
        print("checking1111111")
    while prices.ws.sock is not None:
        print("checking2222222")
        time.sleep(10)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    start()
```

`stream.py`:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from datetime import datetime
import json, websocket, time
from event import TickEvent

class StreamingForexPrices(object):

    def __init__(
        self, events_queue
    ):
        self.events_queue = events_queue
        # self.conn()

    def conn(self):
        self.socket = f'wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/btcusdt@ticker/ethbtc@ticker/bnbbtc@ticker/wavesbtc@ticker/stratbtc@ticker/ethup@ticker/yfiup@ticker/xrpup@ticker'
        websocket.enableTrace(False)
        self.ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(
            self.socket, on_message=self.on_message, on_close=self.on_close)
        self.ws.run_forever()
   
    def on_close(self, ws, message):
        print("bang")

    def on_message(self, ws, message):
        data = json.loads(message)
        timestamp = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(data['E']/1000).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        instrument = data['s']
        open = data['o']
        high = data['h']
        low = data['l']
        close = data['c']
        volume = data['v']
        trade = data['n']
        tev = TickEvent(instrument, timestamp, open, high, low, close, volume, trade)
        self.events_queue.put(tev)
```

There is also a similar question related to this issue in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38377276/10401287) but i am not able to figure out how to resolve this issue with a queue variable.

`Event.py`:

```
class Event(object):
    pass


class TickEvent(Event):
    def __init__(self, instrument, time, open, high, low, close, volume, trade):
        self.type = 'TICK'
        self.instrument = instrument
        self.time = time
        self.open = open
        self.high = high
        self.low = low
        self.close = close
        self.high = high
        self.volume = volume
        self.trade = trade
        # print(self.type, self.instrument, self.open, self.close, self.high)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Type: %s, Instrument: %s, Time: %s, open: %s, high: %s, low: %s, close: %s, volume: %s, trade: %s" % (
            str(self.type), str(self.instrument),
            str(self.time), str(self.open), str(self.high),
            str(self.low), str(self.close), str(self.volume),
            str(self.trade)
        )

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)
```

Comment: Where are you accessing `prices.events_queue`?

Comment: I am accessing with `fetch_data` function with `data_q` variable in `fetch_thread`

Comment: Why don't you use the `block=True` option when calling `get()`? Otherwise you'll get an error if the prices thread doesn't queue something fast enough.

Comment: This might be working but `data = data_q.get(False) print(data)`  is not printing any data in my `console`, how should i make sure that i am receiving the data?

Comment: are you sure it's putting into the queue? Add a print statement to the prices thread.

Comment: Yes i am sure i have put `data_q.put("checking")` in 'fetch_data' function below 'time.sleep(10)' line and it is printing that string in my console but not the data received from websocket

Comment: I mean put `print('Queuing', tev)` in the queuing function.

Comment: To call `self.tev` first i need to call `self.on_message`  function because the `self.tev` is not defined in the `class` directly. It is throwing not defined error. If i defined in `__init__` with 'None' it will get only `None` value. Please check my provided link down in the question

Comment: I meant to put that right before `self.events_queue.put(tev)` so you know that you're queuing something.

Comment: I understand what you meant but it does not `print` any variable that are inside that `StreamingForexPrices` to my main console.

Comment: Then the `on_message` function is never being called, and that's why nothing is in the queue.

Comment: Well i am calling it with `conn` function with `self.on_message`. I have checked with other git hub codes they are doing in the same way but it is not going with me.

Comment: I can see what you're doing very clearly. For some reason you're not getting any messages from the websocket connection. Maybe try turning on tracing?

Comment: Enabling tracing throws me call back error on websocket.  Sir would you please run my code on your system to make a better understanding about the issue.

Comment: I'm getting an error with `pip install event` because it needs python 2.x.

Comment: I have edited the question with `Event` class Please check.

Comment: I'm getting errors: module 'websocket' has no attribute 'WebSocketApp'

Comment: try `pip install websocket-client`

Comment: I added `print('in on_message')` to the `on_message` function, it never printed anything. So it's not getting anything from the socket.

Comment: I think the problem is with the `class` structure of python unless the function is not called the variable inside that function will not be accessed as you can see in my provided link. do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: It has nothing to do with variables. The `on_message` function is never being called.

Comment: The `on_message` function is being called with `self.ws.run_forever()` and it is in their documentation too. you can check a similar application in github https://github.com/sc1f/perspective-order-book/blob/84de77b3810aee4651ebcdeb5e127c9c3e4e9478/src/server/server.py

Comment: It only gets called when the websocket receives a message.

Comment: It is a live server i have tested it without `class` structure of python and it is working well but not working properly with `class` structure.

Comment: You can check this link to get a view of binance through websocket https://github.com/Ebanchous/binance_websockets/blob/3c4c9bec47c44c09a6432a5d5fadd29a1e33b4cf/binance_websockets.py

Comment: I am not sure what your asking. Running this code gives me "checking11..\nchecking2...\nTYPE.<binance ticker info>\nchecking222...\n" and so on. Are you not getting this? If so, you should check if your network works (i.e. I think the problem lies outside Python code)

Comment: Thanks for your response. In my class `StreamingForexPrices` i am putting received ticks value inside the queue with `on_message` function i.e  `self.events_queue.put(tev)` and trying to get the values from the queue with `fetch_data` function in `main.py` script. This should print the received data in my terminal but it is getting `empty queue`.